# Quick question on Mobius Transformation Iteration

Tags: group-theory, mobius-transformation

If f and g are Mobius Transformations, why does this hold?

$$gf^{n}g^{-1}(z)=z+n$$ implies $$f^{n}(z)=g^{-1}(g(z)+n) $$

Comment: hey jesse and welcome to the site, I tried helping with some typesetting, you can click edit and change stuff if it does not look the way you want.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks!

Comment: Also can be good to know that showing what you have tried can increase the chances of getting good responses. Some percent of all downvotes are to reduce "please do my homework for me" type of questions as we do get quite some of those from time to time.

Comment: This isn't homework, it is just part of some lecture notes that is meant to be a trivial statement but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: It should be trivial and doesn't require $f$ and $g$ to be mobius transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try substituting $g(w)$ for $z$ in your first equation, and then do everything you can to simplify and get an expression for $f^n(w)$.

(Then you can replace $w$ with any other symbol you like...such as $z$.)